# How to invoke a flow from a public class

Tags: apex, flow, emailmessage

I am having problems to invoke a flow from Apex. I would like to pass EmailMessage objetc to the flow but I have the next Problem:

**Constructor not defined: [Flow.Interview.Asociado_correo_secundario_al_EmailMessage].(EmailMessage)**

This is the part of the code:

```
public void beforeInsert(SObject so){
    EmailMessage email = (EmailMessage)so;

    Map<String, Object> myMap = new Map<String, Object>();
    myMap.put('RecuperarEmail', email);
    system.debug('emailMessage'+ email);
    Flow.Interview.Asociado_correo_secundario_al_EmailMessage procesoEmailSecundario = new Flow.Interview.Asociado_correo_secundario_al_EmailMessage(myMap);
    procesoEmailSecundario.start();
    system.debug('pasa por el flow');
    Double returnValue = (Double) procesoEmailSecundario.getVariableValue(email.ToAddress);
    System.debug('Flow returned ' + returnValue);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Invoke a Flow with Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_system_apex.htm). Basically, you must supply a map with the variables you want to use:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = new Map<String, Object>();
myMap.put('emailVariableName', emailMessageList);
Flow.Interview.Asociado_correo_secundario_al_EmailMessage flow = new Flow.Interview.Asociado_correo_secundario_al_EmailMessage(myMap);
flow.start();
```

Comment: I should first of all like to thank you for the answer. 
I made some changes in the code but it is not yet running.

Comment: @Borjaglezabajo but what happens when you try to run it now?

Comment: Nothing, the flow not run. I know flow is correct because when I invoke it from Process Builder run correctly but I need to do it from Apex.